# I can't swap my left and right mouse buttons

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I am using 16.04 and have a Polaroid wireless mouse, which has worked perfectly until I rebooted my laptop about fifteen minutes ago. When it started back up, my mouse buttons were the wrong way around (as a leftie, the first thing I do when I install a new system is to change the buttons so that the right side is the primary button).

I've tried going into "Mouse settings", and no matter whether I click "left" or "ight", the mouse stays the same. I've tried creating an "Xmodmap" file in my Home folder and putting in a "pointer 3 2 1" line, and it stays the same.

Can anyone help, please? It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal and enter the following command:

```
echo xmodmap -e \"pointer = 3 2 1\" 2\> /dev/null >> ~/.xprofile
```

Then when you log in the buttons will be swapped.